# How can I imitate a coffee yoghurt?

Tags: substitutions, coffee, yogurt

I used to enjoy coffee yoghurts and eat them often... However, where I'm currently living coffee-flavored yoghurts are unavailable. I've tried to sort of make my own by adding a bit of instant coffee mix and some sugar to plain yoghurt, but it doesn't taste nearly the same. Are there any other ingredients I can try adding? Has anyone ever tried this?

Comment: Have you tried mixing in Kahlúa? Shouldn't need much... And should be plenty sweet enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Instant" coffee typically is disolved in hot water, so I'd think that just stirring it into a cold product would be less than ideal.

You might try [making a coffee syrup](http://www.food.com/recipe/coffee-syrup-24775) (as you're adding sugar anyway) or try steeping the instant coffee in hot milk or water first, cool it down, then mixing that into the yoghurt.

Comment: thanks! not sure why I didn't think of this... just dissolving the coffee and sugar in a bit of hot water before adding it to the yoghurt makes a big difference!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to really depend on the quality of the instant coffee you use. Go to Starbucks and pick up a packet of Via, it is probably the best tasting instant on the market. Start with about 1/4 packet for a 6 ounce yogurt and work your way up from there. You might want to add a bit of sugar too.

Answer (score 1):

I used to like getting a coffee cream chocolate (out of standard boxes of say  'Milk Tray' or whatever) and melting it into my yoghurt. Try it, you might like it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the instant coffee and just stir in a bit of regular coffee that's been made and sweetened to your taste.

Comment: I suspect normal coffee might have too much water per flavor to work well for mixing into yogurt.

Comment: @Jefromi - That's a good point, so perhaps a strongly brewed non-instant coffee would be ideal in terms of quality.  The commercially made coffee flavoured yogourts are probably completely artificial flavours and lots of extra sugar, so it depends on if the goal is pure imitation or just yummy coffee flavoured results.

Answer (score 0):

I added this stuff to Greek yogurt (naturally tart, not sweetened) when we were there and it's fantastic. Apparently this guy is bringing it to the states. http://bit.ly/11C5zbs